# Multiple Uniques MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code im trying to get working.  What im looking for is to have it so that i query a site, then display results and upload to database.  I want it to ignore duplicates which i have working by checking the date.  issue im having is when a user searches for another stock ticker it does not insert into DB because the date is the same.  Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bbpinpal_stocks", $con);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stocks (stock_name, stock_value, stock_perc, date)
VALUES ('$name', '$last','$perc2', '$date')");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stocks");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Percent Change</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['stock_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['stock_value'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['stock_perc'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  } 
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have set date to unique but i know that is prob my issue.  How can i have this so that it checks both name and date and if match to ignore

Comment: Can you not use a unique auto incrementing id to check against instead?

Comment: If I get you right you want to avoid duplicates? To do so, write "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM stocks" on your query.

Comment: isnt the SELECT DISTINCT only for column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have set date to unique but i know that is prob my issue

This is most probably the issue. Why don't you use another column to uniquely identify a row?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key

"..Each unique key is composed from one or more data attributes of that data entity.."

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `UNIQUE` index on `date` with one on `(stock_name, date)`:

```
ALTER TABLE stocks
  DROP KEY date,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY (stock_name, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IGNORE prevents you adding data with a primary key that is already in the database. You can have a primary key that consists of 2 fields.